# dynamic CSS for span tag hover--when hover move on ol li span for my web page issue

Tags: css

I have a Dynamic CSS problem for span tag--when hover move on ol li span with class name cateChooseList -for my web page

By deleting of Browser History -Problem fixed and again issue reproduced after few days.

Details:
There is web page with some Html section containing item list using ol> li >span tags

In each item of list there is span tag which contains a tag and on Hover on Span ...that tag a visible.and parent item have css class 'cateChooseList'.

Some time  on Hover span item - tag a is not visible and clearing on browser history everything gets fine.and gain reproduced after fews days which is an Issue.....

Dynamic CSS for permalink option in  a tag--when over move on ol li span with class name cateChooseList

```
.cateChooseList ol li:hover >span{display:block}
```

Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific, try to post a larger piece of code including both `html` and `css3` parts, maybe the problem is in another part and you are not searching the right one.